# Invoking "make -j1 -l1" failed

Tags: catkin-make, catkin, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Trying to set up a ROS environment in Ubuntu with the instructions here:

http://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/pc_software_setup/#install-ubuntu-on-remote-pc-desktop-or-laptop-pc

I run into an error at step 5.2.1 after the last command below.

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
$ wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/robotis_tools/master/install_ros_kinetic.sh && chmod 755 ./install_ros_kinetic.sh && bash ./install_ros_kinetic.sh
```

> error: ‘const struct turtlebot3_msgs::SensorState_std::allocator<void’ has no member named ‘torque’
> if (msg->torque == true)
> ^ turtlebot3/turtlebot3_bringup/CMakeFiles/turtlebot3_diagnostics.dir/build.make:62:
> recipe for target
> 'turtlebot3/turtlebot3_bringup/CMakeFiles/turtlebot3_diagnostics.dir/src/turtlebot3_diagnostics.cpp.o'
> failed make[2]: ***
> [turtlebot3/turtlebot3_bringup/CMakeFiles/turtlebot3_diagnostics.dir/src/turtlebot3_diagnostics.cpp.o]
> Error 1 CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1892:
> recipe for target
> 'turtlebot3/turtlebot3_bringup/CMakeFiles/turtlebot3_diagnostics.dir/all'
> failed make[1]: ***
> [turtlebot3/turtlebot3_bringup/CMakeFiles/turtlebot3_diagnostics.dir/all]
> Error 2 Makefile:138: recipe for
> target 'all' failed make: *** [all]
> Error 2 Invoking "make -j1 -l1" failed

Any thoughts on what may be causing this? I get the same error if I try to run catkin_make after following the emanual robotics instructions as well.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280192/invoking-%22make--j1--l1%22-failed/) by [nickapril](https://answers.ros.org/users/33340/nickapril/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-01-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have encountered a similar problem with the same error output:

`error: ‘const struct turtlebot3_msgs::SensorState_<std::allocator<void>’ has no member named ‘torque’  if (msg->torque == true) ^`

**Explaination:**
There is no current message that has the format **turtlebot3_msgs::SensorState** which can be found in your catkin_ws workspace.

**Steps To Rectify:**

**1**. Follow the steps after where you left off at step 5.2.1 (Here's the link again.[Click Here](http://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/pc_setup/#install-ros-on-remote-pc))

**2**. Under **6.3 Install Independent Packages**, ensure that you are in your `catkin_ws/src` and run the following command according to the emanual.

`$ git clone https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3_msgs.git`

This is where the **turtlebot3_msgs::SensorState** message is located.

**3**. Return back to the root of your catkin_ws  by running `$ cd ~/catkin_ws`

**4**. run `$ source devel/setup.bash`

**5**. run `$ catkin_make`

It worked for me. Hopes it works for you as well.

---

Originally posted by [cardboardros](https://answers.ros.org/users/33946/cardboardros/) with karma: 26 on 2018-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1